# UIImagePickerController crashes on iOS7

Tags: objective-c

```
if ([UIImagePickerControllerisSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagePicker  = imagePicker;
   [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can't get anymore simple than that. However, when this code runs, I get this:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Argh. What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT: Its not my code causing the exception

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' 
*** First throw call stack: 
(0x184a53100 0x190f5c1fc 0x18495d37c 0x18495d1c4 0x187a963a8 0x187a26efc 0x18c40dd8c 0x187a16fe0 0x187608258 0x187602e20 0x187602cd8 0x187602560 0x187602304 0x1875fbc38 0x184a13858 0x184a10ae0 0x184a10e6c 0x184951dd0 0x18a639c0c 0x187a82fc4 0x100077f24 0x19154faa0) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

EDIT 2: Adding the exception breakpoint detail

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x190f5c1c0:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #-16]!
0x190f5c1c4:  add    fp, sp, 0
0x190f5c1c8:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-16]!
0x190f5c1cc:  stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-16]!
0x190f5c1d0:  stp    x24, x23, [sp, #-16]!
0x190f5c1d4:  sub    sp, sp, #4032
0x190f5c1d8:  mov    x20, x0
0x190f5c1dc:  orr    x0, sp, #0x20
0x190f5c1e0:  bl     0x190f778e4               ; symbol stub for: +[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:]
0x190f5c1e4:  mov    x19, x0
0x190f5c1e8:  adrp   x8, 13401
0x190f5c1ec:  add    x8, x8, 1552
0x190f5c1f0:  ldr    x8, [x8, 0]
0x190f5c1f4:  mov    x0, x20
0x190f5c1f8:  blr    x8
0x190f5c1fc:  mov    x20, x0
0x190f5c200:  adrp   x8, 13400
0x190f5c204:  add    x8, x8, 2616
0x190f5c208:  ldr    x1, [x8, 0]
0x190f5c20c:  bl     0x190f6c1c0               ; objc_msgSend
0x190f5c210:  str    x20, [x19]
0x190f5c214:  adrp   x8, 13401
0x190f5c218:  add    x8, x8, 1928
0x190f5c21c:  add    x8, x8, 16
0x190f5c220:  mov    x21, x19
0x190f5c224:  str    x8, [x21, #8]!
0x190f5c228:  mov    x0, x20
0x190f5c22c:  bl     0x190f5a540               ; object_getClassName
0x190f5c230:  movz   x8, #0
0x190f5c234:  str    x0, [x19, #16]
0x190f5c238:  cbz    x20, 0x190f5c264          ; objc_exception_throw + 164
0x190f5c23c:  cmn    x20, #0
0x190f5c240:  b.ge   0x190f5c25c               ; objc_exception_throw + 156
0x190f5c244:  lsr    x8, x20, #57
0x190f5c248:  and    x8, x8, #0x78
0x190f5c24c:  adrp   x9, 13401
0x190f5c250:  add    x9, x9, 2144
0x190f5c254:  ldr    x8, [x9, x8]
0x190f5c258:  b      0x190f5c264               ; objc_exception_throw + 164
0x190f5c25c:  ldr    x8, [x20, 0]
0x190f5c260:  and    x8, x8, #0x1fffffff8
0x190f5c264:  str    x8, [x19, #24]
0x190f5c268:  adrp   x22, 13410
0x190f5c26c:  add    x22, x22, 2742
0x190f5c270:  ldrb   w8, [x22]
0x190f5c274:  cbz    w8, 0x190f5c294           ; objc_exception_throw + 212
0x190f5c278:  mov    x0, x20
0x190f5c27c:  bl     0x190f5a540               ; object_getClassName
0x190f5c280:  stp    x20, x0, [sp, #8]
0x190f5c284:  str    x19, [sp]
0x190f5c288:  adrp   x0, 28
0x190f5c28c:  add    x0, x0, 2824
0x190f5c290:  bl     0x190f5bd54               ; _objc_inform
0x190f5c294:  adrp   x8, 13410
0x190f5c298:  add    x8, x8, 2743
0x190f5c29c:  ldrb   w8, [x8]
0x190f5c2a0:  cbz    w8, 0x190f5c2fc           ; objc_exception_throw + 316
0x190f5c2a4:  ldrb   w8, [x22]
0x190f5c2a8:  cbnz   w8, 0x190f5c2c8           ; objc_exception_throw + 264
0x190f5c2ac:  mov    x0, x20
0x190f5c2b0:  bl     0x190f5a540               ; object_getClassName
0x190f5c2b4:  stp    x20, x0, [sp, #8]
0x190f5c2b8:  str    x19, [sp]
0x190f5c2bc:  adrp   x0, 28
0x190f5c2c0:  add    x0, x0, 2824
0x190f5c2c4:  bl     0x190f5bd54               ; _objc_inform
0x190f5c2c8:  add    x22, sp, 32
0x190f5c2cc:  movz   w1, #500
0x190f5c2d0:  mov    x0, x22
0x190f5c2d4:  bl     0x190f77a64               ; symbol stub for: +[NSObject resolveInstanceMethod:]
0x190f5c2d8:  mov    x23, x0
0x190f5c2dc:  adrp   x8, 13399
0x190f5c2e0:  ldr    x8, [x8, 5]
0x190f5c2e4:  ldr    x0, [x8, 0]
0x190f5c2e8:  bl     0x190f77ae8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSObject methodSignatureForSelector:]
0x190f5c2ec:  mov    x2, x0
0x190f5c2f0:  mov    x0, x22
0x190f5c2f4:  mov    x1, x23
0x190f5c2f8:  bl     0x190f77a7c               ; symbol stub for: -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
0x190f5c2fc:  mov    x0, x20
0x190f5c300:  nop    
0x190f5c304:  adrp   x2, 0
0x190f5c308:  add    x2, x2, 792
0x190f5c30c:  mov    x0, x19
0x190f5c310:  mov    x1, x21
0x190f5c314:  bl     0x190f77920               ; symbol stub for: +[NSObject conformsToProtocol:]
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the crash? Nothing you posted deals with creating an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: It's not the code you posted either. Other than the fact that you don't assign `imagePicker` to the `self.imagePicker` property you're presenting (which I assume is a typo here), that snippet should work.

Comment: I added the exception breakpoint detail. Its not particularly illuminating.

Comment: I placed your code into an empty project and it worked fine with no crashes. There must be some other surrounding code that is causing the issue. Have you implemented any of the UINavigationControllerDelegate or UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods? Also, can you try taking out all of the code you have above and replace it with a simple log and see if the crash still happens.  Perhaps it's something along the same code path but unrelated.

Comment: Please see http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash like this.

Comment: read it - my stacktrace isn't helping me any

Answer (score -2):

may be your app crash because of this line

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

replce it with below line

```
controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
```

this is the code for UIImagePickerController

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    controller.allowsEditing = NO;
    controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

}

UIImagePickerController Delegate Method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    YourImageView.image = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to deal with the question which is about an exception (crash).